# How to end-to-end test notifications in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-integration-test, flutter-notification

I have a flutter app that uses `flutter_local_notifications` package to show notifications.

Is it possible to have `integration_test` in form of end-to-end tests like this:

- notification is scheduled (e.g. 10 seconds in future), app is closed, notification is shown, clicked, and app opens with desired result
- notification is scheduled (e.g. 10 seconds in future), app is kept open, notification is shown, clicked, and app opens with desired result
- etc.

Answer (score 1):

See the [Patrol framework](https://patrol.leancode.co/) – it lets you easily test many native features, like notifications!

[Here's](https://github.com/leancodepl/patrol/blob/master/packages/patrol/example/integration_test/notifications_test.dart) an example integration test testing notifications.

It has extensive documentation and is actively maintained.

Disclaimer: I'm Patrol's lead dev.